# Why does DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH have an implicit commit?

Tags: oracle, transactions, materialized-views

I noticed recently that calling dbms_mview.refresh(...), which refreshes materialized views in Oracle, has an implicit commit.

Any ideas - other than "because it does" - why this action has an implicit commit?

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your Oracle version and/or the parameters you supply dbms_mview.refresh may be doing a TRUNCATE followed by a direct load.  TRUNCATE is a DDL command and as such issues an implicit commit.  Direct load does not require a commit.

If you are using a more recent version of Oracle, I think 10.2+, you can set the atomic_refresh parameter to TRUE and it will refresh within a single transaction, using standard DELETE / INSERTs.  This method could be quite a bit slower though.

Comment: An implicit commit is done even when atomic_refresh is true, but you are correct about the TRUNCATE/DELETE behavior.

Comment: Yep - I suppose the implicit commit makes the behaviour consistent regardless of the refresh mechanism.

Answer (score 6):

According to Tom Kyte it is because [a decision was made at design time to consider refreshing to be a DDL operation](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4541191739042).  Since all DDL operations implicitly commit, so does this one.  Unfortunatly he doesn't answer the resulting question of why they choose to make it DDL.

Comment: Tom is great, but he does tend to throw out these "because it does" answers.

Comment: Yes he does and they are usually to questions that no one else can answer either.

Answer (score 0):

A work arround is to do the call to dbms_mview.refresh in an autonomous transaction (create a PL/SQL procedure with pragma autonomous_transaction).

Comment: Not in this case, I wanted to be able to rollback a refresh if the refreshed view itself was screwed up.